# Shared pointee is not the same in the caller and the callee

Tags: c++, pointers, ns-3

I am working on a module of the [ns-3](/questions/tagged/ns-3) simulator. For people unfamiliar with it, they exhibit a custom-made shared pointer: [`Ptr<T>`](https://github.com/nsnam/ns-3-dev-git/blob/master/src/core/model/ptr.h). These objects are usually created using the [`CreateObject<T>(…)`](https://github.com/nsnam/ns-3-dev-git/blob/master/src/core/model/object.h#L524-L667) function which basically calls `new T(…)` and wraps it in a `Ptr<T>`.

I’m having troubles using one of these that I created in a constructor:

```
SatUtHelper::SatUtHelper (SatTypedefs::CarrierBandwidthConverter_t carrierBandwidthConverter,
                          uint32_t fwdLinkCarrierCount,
                          Ptr<SatSuperframeSeq> seq,
                          SatMac::ReadCtrlMsgCallback readCb,
                          SatMac::ReserveCtrlMsgCallback reserveCb,
                          SatMac::SendCtrlMsgCallback sendCb,
                          RandomAccessSettings_s randomAccessSettings)
  : m_superframeSeq (seq),
  m_llsConf (),
  [...snip...]
{
  [...snip...]
  m_llsConf = CreateObject<SatLowerLayerServiceConf>  ();
}
```

and that I use like so:

```
Ptr<SatRandomAccessConf> randomAccessConf = CreateObject<SatRandomAccessConf> (m_llsConf, m_superframeSeq);
```

---

The `SatRandomAccessConf` constructor begins like so:

```
SatRandomAccessConf::SatRandomAccessConf (Ptr<SatLowerLayerServiceConf> llsConf, Ptr<SatSuperframeSeq> superframeSeq)
  : m_configurationIdPerAllocationChannel (),
  m_slottedAlohaControlRandomizationIntervalInMilliSeconds (),
  m_allocationChannelCount (llsConf->GetRaServiceCount ()),
  m_crdsaSignalingOverheadInBytes (5),
  m_slottedAlohaSignalingOverheadInBytes (3)
{
  NS_LOG_FUNCTION (this);

  if (m_allocationChannelCount < 1)
    {
      NS_FATAL_ERROR ("SatRandomAccessConf::SatRandomAccessConf - No random access allocation channel");
    }

  m_slottedAlohaControlRandomizationIntervalInMilliSeconds = (llsConf->GetDefaultControlRandomizationInterval ()).GetMilliSeconds ();
  DoSlottedAlohaVariableSanityCheck ();
```

and contains some checks past that point which blows up due to having `llsConf` in an incoherent state.

---

I have used GDB to inspect the state of the `llsConf` object:

- I put a breakpoint on the `DoSlottedAlohaVariableSanityCheck ()`;
- I called methods on `llsConf` that indeed returned garbage values;
- I checked values of `m_allocationChannelCount` and `m_slottedAlohaControlRandomizationIntervalInMilliSeconds` that were **not** the same as the return values from the methods of `llsConf`;
- I checked in upper frames the values on `m_llsConf` which were as expected;
- I checked the content of the objects in both frames that differed in the caller and the callee; the content of `llsConf` having a suspiciously large amount of attributes set to `0`.

Relevant parts of the GDB session:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  ns3::SatRandomAccessConf::DoSlottedAlohaVariableSanityCheck (this=0x55555a160a00) at ../contrib/satellite/model/satellite-random-access-container-conf.cc:146
#1  0x00007ffff76fe0e1 in ns3::SatRandomAccessConf::SatRandomAccessConf (this=0x55555a160a00, llsConf=..., superframeSeq=...) at ../contrib/satellite/model/satellite-random-access-container-conf.cc:75
#2  0x00007ffff781fa26 in ns3::CreateObject<ns3::SatRandomAccessConf, ns3::Ptr<ns3::SatLowerLayerServiceConf>, ns3::Ptr<ns3::SatSuperframeSeq> > (a1=..., a2=...) at ./ns3/object.h:557
#3  0x00007ffff781d494 in ns3::SatUtHelper::Install (this=0x555555841990, n=..., beamId=10, fCh=..., rCh=..., gwNd=..., ncc=..., cbChannel=..., cbRouting=...) at ../contrib/satellite/helper/satellite-ut-helper.cc:425
#4  0x00007ffff781b307 in ns3::SatUtHelper::Install (this=0x555555841990, c=..., beamId=10, fCh=..., rCh=..., gwNd=..., ncc=..., cbChannel=..., cbRouting=...) at ../contrib/satellite/helper/satellite-ut-helper.cc:231
#5  0x00007ffff77b03bc in ns3::SatBeamHelper::Install (this=0x5555557ecb20, ut=..., gwNode=..., gwId=3, beamId=10, ulFreqId=3, flFreqId=1, routingCallback=...) at ../contrib/satellite/helper/satellite-beam-helper.cc:475
#6  0x00007ffff77f0262 in ns3::SatHelper::DoCreateScenario (this=0x5555557ec810, beamInfos=std::map with 0 elements, gwUsers=1) at ../contrib/satellite/helper/satellite-helper.cc:566
#7  0x00007ffff77ee873 in ns3::SatHelper::CreateUserDefinedScenario (this=0x5555557ec810, infos=std::map with 0 elements) at ../contrib/satellite/helper/satellite-helper.cc:389
#8  0x00007ffff7844e0b in ns3::SimulationHelper::CreateSatScenario (this=0x5555557ec5a0, scenario=ns3::SatHelper::NONE, mobileUtsFolder="contrib/satellite/data/utpositions/mobiles/")
    at ../contrib/satellite/helper/simulation-helper.cc:1170
#9  0x00007ffff784a1dc in ns3::SimulationHelper::ConfigureAttributesFromFile (this=0x5555557ec5a0, filePath="/tmp/sns-3-qs4ebg47/parameters.xml", overrideManualConfiguration=true) at ../contrib/satellite/helper/simulation-helper.cc:1555
#10 0x0000555555557225 in main (argc=3, argv=0x7fffffffe798) at ../contrib/satellite/examples/sat-generic-launcher.cc:60
(gdb) p llsConf->GetRaServiceCount()
$1 = 0 '\000'
(gdb) p llsConf->GetDefaultControlRandomizationInterval()
$2 = {static g_markingTimes = 0x7ffff39447a0 <ns3::Time::StaticInit()::markingTimes>, m_data = 93824994540112}
(gdb) p llsConf->GetDefaultControlRandomizationInterval().GetMilliSeconds()
$3 = 93824994
(gdb) p m_allocationChannelCount 
$4 = 1
(gdb) p m_slottedAlohaControlRandomizationIntervalInMilliSeconds 
$5 = 100
(gdb) p llsConf
$6 = {m_ptr = 0x7fffffffd718}
(gdb) p *(llsConf.m_ptr)
$7 = {<ns3::Object> = {<ns3::SimpleRefCount<ns3::Object, ns3::ObjectBase, ns3::ObjectDeleter>> = {<ns3::ObjectBase> = {_vptr.ObjectBase = 0x5555557af810}, m_count = 1434627024}, m_tid = {m_tid = 21845}, m_disposed = false, 
    m_initialized = false, m_aggregates = 0x91c8f8cb8ee26900, m_getObjectCount = 0}, static m_minDaServiceEntries = 2 '\002', static m_minRaServiceEntries = 1 '\001', static m_maxDaServiceEntries = 4 '\004', 
  static m_maxRaServiceEntries = 3 '\003', m_dynamicRatePersistence = 0 '\000', m_volumeBacklogPersistence = 0 '\000', m_defaultControlRandomizationInterval = {
    static g_markingTimes = 0x7ffff39447a0 <ns3::Time::StaticInit()::markingTimes>, m_data = 93824994540112}, m_daServiceEntryCount = 102 'f', m_daServiceEntries = {{m_constantAssignmentProvided = false, m_rbdcAllowed = false, 
      m_volumeAllowed = false, m_constantServiceRateStream = {m_ptr = 0x7fffffffdb50}, m_maximumServiceRateKbps = 54420, m_minimumServiceRateKbps = 63361, m_maximumBacklogInKbytes = 32767}, {m_constantAssignmentProvided = 54, 
      m_rbdcAllowed = 62, m_volumeAllowed = 103, m_constantServiceRateStream = {m_ptr = 0x0}, m_maximumServiceRateKbps = 51468, m_minimumServiceRateKbps = 63349, m_maximumBacklogInKbytes = 32767}, {m_constantAssignmentProvided = false, 
      m_rbdcAllowed = false, m_volumeAllowed = false, m_constantServiceRateStream = {m_ptr = 0x7ffff7710ce6 <ns3::SatRequestManager::AssignedDaResources(unsigned char, unsigned int)>}, m_maximumServiceRateKbps = 0, 
      m_minimumServiceRateKbps = 0, m_maximumBacklogInKbytes = 0}, {m_constantAssignmentProvided = 192, m_rbdcAllowed = 189, m_volumeAllowed = 112, m_constantServiceRateStream = {m_ptr = 0x0}, m_maximumServiceRateKbps = 65, 
      m_minimumServiceRateKbps = 0, m_maximumBacklogInKbytes = 0}}, m_raServiceIndexDefault = 0 '\000', m_raServiceEntryCount = 0 '\000', m_raServiceEntries = {{m_maxUniquePayloadPerBlock = 118 'v', 
      m_maxConsecutiveBlockAccessed = 130 '\202', m_minimumIdleBlock = 112 'p', m_backOffTimeInMilliSeconds = 32767, m_highLoadBackOffTimeInMilliSeconds = 0, m_backOffProbability = 0, m_highLoadBackOffProbability = 0, 
      m_numberOfInstances = 0 '\000', m_averageNormalizedOfferedLoadThreshold = 6.9533487051292957e-310, m_isCrdsaAllowed = false, m_isSlottedAlohaAllowed = false}, {m_maxUniquePayloadPerBlock = 54 '6', 
      m_maxConsecutiveBlockAccessed = 62 '>', m_minimumIdleBlock = 103 'g', m_backOffTimeInMilliSeconds = 32767, m_highLoadBackOffTimeInMilliSeconds = 0, m_backOffProbability = 0, m_highLoadBackOffProbability = 0, 
      m_numberOfInstances = 0 '\000', m_averageNormalizedOfferedLoadThreshold = 7.5592043813710721e-322, m_isCrdsaAllowed = false, m_isSlottedAlohaAllowed = false}, {m_maxUniquePayloadPerBlock = 113 'q', 
      m_maxConsecutiveBlockAccessed = 0 '\000', m_minimumIdleBlock = 0 '\000', m_backOffTimeInMilliSeconds = 0, m_highLoadBackOffTimeInMilliSeconds = 0, m_backOffProbability = 0, m_highLoadBackOffProbability = 0, 
      m_numberOfInstances = 0 '\000', m_averageNormalizedOfferedLoadThreshold = 6.9533487349484301e-310, m_isCrdsaAllowed = false, m_isSlottedAlohaAllowed = false}}}
(gdb) up
#2  0x00007ffff781fa26 in ns3::CreateObject<ns3::SatRandomAccessConf, ns3::Ptr<ns3::SatLowerLayerServiceConf>, ns3::Ptr<ns3::SatSuperframeSeq> > (a1=..., a2=...) at ./ns3/object.h:557
557   return CompleteConstruct (new T (a1,a2));
(gdb) up
#3  0x00007ffff781d494 in ns3::SatUtHelper::Install (this=0x555555841990, n=..., beamId=10, fCh=..., rCh=..., gwNd=..., ncc=..., cbChannel=..., cbRouting=...) at ../contrib/satellite/helper/satellite-ut-helper.cc:425
425       Ptr<SatRandomAccessConf> randomAccessConf = CreateObject<SatRandomAccessConf> (m_llsConf, m_superframeSeq);
(gdb) p m_llsConf->GetRaServiceCount()
$8 = 1 '\001'
(gdb) p m_llsConf->GetDefaultControlRandomizationInterval().GetMilliSeconds()
$9 = 100
(gdb) p m_llsConf
$10 = {m_ptr = 0x5555557af810}
(gdb) p *(m_llsConf.m_ptr)
$11 = {<ns3::Object> = {<ns3::SimpleRefCount<ns3::Object, ns3::ObjectBase, ns3::ObjectDeleter>> = {<ns3::ObjectBase> = {_vptr.ObjectBase = 0x7ffff7d93850 <vtable for ns3::SatLowerLayerServiceConf+16>}, m_count = 6}, m_tid = {
      m_tid = 406}, m_disposed = false, m_initialized = false, m_aggregates = 0x5555564d2540, m_getObjectCount = 0}, static m_minDaServiceEntries = 2 '\002', static m_minRaServiceEntries = 1 '\001', 
  static m_maxDaServiceEntries = 4 '\004', static m_maxRaServiceEntries = 3 '\003', m_dynamicRatePersistence = 5 '\005', m_volumeBacklogPersistence = 7 '\a', m_defaultControlRandomizationInterval = {
    static g_markingTimes = 0x7ffff39447a0 <ns3::Time::StaticInit()::markingTimes>, m_data = 100000000}, m_daServiceEntryCount = 4 '\004', m_daServiceEntries = {{m_constantAssignmentProvided = false, m_rbdcAllowed = false, 
      m_volumeAllowed = false, m_constantServiceRateStream = {m_ptr = 0x5555561d07d0}, m_maximumServiceRateKbps = 9216, m_minimumServiceRateKbps = 10, m_maximumBacklogInKbytes = 384}, {m_constantAssignmentProvided = false, 
      m_rbdcAllowed = false, m_volumeAllowed = false, m_constantServiceRateStream = {m_ptr = 0x555555e48b20}, m_maximumServiceRateKbps = 9216, m_minimumServiceRateKbps = 10, m_maximumBacklogInKbytes = 384}, {
      m_constantAssignmentProvided = false, m_rbdcAllowed = false, m_volumeAllowed = false, m_constantServiceRateStream = {m_ptr = 0x55555581d600}, m_maximumServiceRateKbps = 9216, m_minimumServiceRateKbps = 10, 
      m_maximumBacklogInKbytes = 384}, {m_constantAssignmentProvided = false, m_rbdcAllowed = false, m_volumeAllowed = false, m_constantServiceRateStream = {m_ptr = 0x5555557a95f0}, m_maximumServiceRateKbps = 9216, 
      m_minimumServiceRateKbps = 16, m_maximumBacklogInKbytes = 384}}, m_raServiceIndexDefault = 0 '\000', m_raServiceEntryCount = 1 '\001', m_raServiceEntries = {{m_maxUniquePayloadPerBlock = 1 '\001', 
      m_maxConsecutiveBlockAccessed = 6 '\006', m_minimumIdleBlock = 0 '\000', m_backOffTimeInMilliSeconds = 150, m_highLoadBackOffTimeInMilliSeconds = 500, m_backOffProbability = 1, m_highLoadBackOffProbability = 1, 
      m_numberOfInstances = 3 '\003', m_averageNormalizedOfferedLoadThreshold = 0.98999999999999999, m_isCrdsaAllowed = true, m_isSlottedAlohaAllowed = true}, {m_maxUniquePayloadPerBlock = 3 '\003', 
      m_maxConsecutiveBlockAccessed = 4 '\004', m_minimumIdleBlock = 2 '\002', m_backOffTimeInMilliSeconds = 250, m_highLoadBackOffTimeInMilliSeconds = 500, m_backOffProbability = 10000, m_highLoadBackOffProbability = 30000, 
      m_numberOfInstances = 2 '\002', m_averageNormalizedOfferedLoadThreshold = 0.5, m_isCrdsaAllowed = true, m_isSlottedAlohaAllowed = true}, {m_maxUniquePayloadPerBlock = 3 '\003', m_maxConsecutiveBlockAccessed = 4 '\004', 
      m_minimumIdleBlock = 2 '\002', m_backOffTimeInMilliSeconds = 250, m_highLoadBackOffTimeInMilliSeconds = 500, m_backOffProbability = 10000, m_highLoadBackOffProbability = 30000, m_numberOfInstances = 5 '\005', 
      m_averageNormalizedOfferedLoadThreshold = 0.5, m_isCrdsaAllowed = true, m_isSlottedAlohaAllowed = true}}}
```

---

Now if I add the line `Ptr<SatLowerLayerServiceConf> uglyHack = llsConf;` before the breakpoint, I can in fact see that, somehow, they are equal:

```
(gdb) p uglyHack 
$1 = {m_ptr = 0x5555557af810}
(gdb) p llsConf 
$2 = {m_ptr = 0x7fffffffd718}
(gdb) up
#2  0x00007ffff781fa56 in ns3::CreateObject<ns3::SatRandomAccessConf, ns3::Ptr<ns3::SatLowerLayerServiceConf>, ns3::Ptr<ns3::SatSuperframeSeq> > (a1=..., a2=...) at ./ns3/object.h:557
557   return CompleteConstruct (new T (a1,a2));
(gdb) 
#3  0x00007ffff781d4c4 in ns3::SatUtHelper::Install (this=0x555555841990, n=..., beamId=10, fCh=..., rCh=..., gwNd=..., ncc=..., cbChannel=..., cbRouting=...) at ../contrib/satellite/helper/satellite-ut-helper.cc:425
425       Ptr<SatRandomAccessConf> randomAccessConf = CreateObject<SatRandomAccessConf> (m_llsConf, m_superframeSeq);
(gdb) p m_llsConf 
$3 = {m_ptr = 0x5555557af810}
```

Does someone have any idea how the parameter passing and the copy assignment can allow such behaviour?

Comment: Can you print the pointer's value (that is, the target object's address) and see if it differs from place to place?

Comment: @Wyzard Yes, they change: `(gdb) p llsConf
$18 = {m_ptr = 0x7fffffffd718}` in the callee and `(gdb) p m_llsConf
$19 = {m_ptr = 0x5555557af810}` in the caller.

Comment: @Wyzard Note that the values also change for other `Ptr`. In the `SatUtHelper` constructor I have: `(gdb) p seq
$20 = {m_ptr = 0x7fffffffdc10}
(gdb) p m_superframeSeq 
$21 = {m_ptr = 0x55555582abd0}`

Comment: Well, that's why you're seeing different values: you're looking at different objects (and maybe one of them isn't really a valid object at all).  Forget dereferencing the pointer and comparing the values in the fields; you should investigate why that callee has a different pointer than the one its caller was supposed to pass.

Comment: @Wyzard Your question led me to an interesting discovery, see edit. I’m still puzzled at what is going on, though.

Comment: Did you check whether the reference counting is done properly concerning the pointees? Following the link, I got the impression that `NS3::Ptr<>` relys on proper ref-counting in `Ref()` and `Unref()` of pointee class. (Otherwise, strange things probably might happen.)

Comment: @Scheff ref-counting is done very simply [there](https://github.com/nsnam/ns-3-dev-git/blob/master/src/core/model/simple-ref-count.h#L105-L123). Before the call, calling `GetReferenceCount` on `m_llsConf` returns 4. After the call, I have: `(gdb) p llsConf->GetReferenceCount()
$1 = 1434627024
(gdb) p uglyHack->GetReferenceCount ()
$2 = 7
(gdb) p m_llsConf->GetReferenceCount ()
$3 = 7`

Comment: Isn't it strange that the reference count looks like (the lower part of) an address? `1434627024`: `0x5582ABD0` similar like that you exposed in your sample outputs? This can mean something or nothing...

Comment: @Scheff The strangest thing is that both `m_llsConf` and `uglyHack` exhibit a `vtable` entry, but not `llsConf`. Despite them being pretty much the same thing.

Comment: I guess you know what this can mean: U.B., unintended side-effects, access to variables which are not (yet) properly constructed/initialized... (Really sorry, that I've nothing better than these common statements. I will remind it when I'm looking next time for strange behavior in my code...) ;-)

Comment: @Scheff How come something that is fully initialized before a function call and passed as a parameter by copy, suddently becomes "not (yet) properly constructed/initialized"? (I’m not making fun of the statement, I’m genuinely intrigued by the behaviour here.)

Comment: IMHO, the pointee may or may not have a `vtable`, the `Ptr<>` shouldn't have one. (I just looked into the link you provided and couldn't find anything `virtual`. I did this as I remembered that I carefully tried to prevent `virtual` things in our own intrusive smart pointer implementation.)

Comment: @Scheff Yes, my earlier comment was a simplification. `Ptr<T>` does not have a `vtable`. But, in GDB, the pointee of `m_llsConf` and `uglyHack` does have one, but not the pointee of `llsConf`.

Comment: Do you have other threads that can change object values? Try to compile your code with thread and address sanitizers.

Comment: @MichaelVeksler ns-3 is mono-threaded

Comment: @MathiasEttinger in that case, mixed compilation can be a cause. When one translation unit is compiled with one set of flags, and the other with another. For example, if build dependencies are insufficient, or if one translation unit has `#pragma pack` and the other not..If the caller and the callee are in different translation units, I'll print sizeof(...) for the objects in both translation units.Also, it could be that there are two different variants of header files (with similar names), where each translation unit reads a different one for some reason.

Comment: @MichaelVeksler I greped the entire code base and no `#pragma` at all. The build process makes use of [`waf`](https://gitlab.com/ita1024/waf/) to scan for dependencies and generate grouping header for each module. Having two headers with the same name in two different module is possible but stand out in subsequent compilations (which I do often ATM); different set of flags is also unlikely for this reason. I’ll try to print `sizeof` but since assigning to `uglyHack` gives me the original object back, I have little faith in whatever information will come out of this.

Comment: @MathiasEttinger I assume that you compiled both translation units with -O0, or without any -O flag at all